# Facebook Comments Plugin: Latest and Most comments?

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I want to use facebook comments plugin on my website to allow users to comment on the articles on different pages. In that case, would it be possible for me to get a list of for example:

1. Latest comment posted anywhere on the website (for example to display on homepage)?
2. Users list with most number of comments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can analyze your comment plugin data with **Facebook Domain Insights** for your website.

First, you have to enable Facebook Domain Insights by adding a meta tag to your website. By this meta tag you relate your website with a personal Facebook account or a Facebook page. 
You have to add one of these tags to your website:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="user_id" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id" />
```

For documentation about Facebook Domain Insights, please visit the Domain Insights section in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

After enabling, you will see your domain appearing on [Facebook Insights Page](http://www.facebook.com/insights/). Click on Comments Box section to analyze comment plugin data. There are various rich statistics.